# subdomain wordpress can't load theme

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, subdomain

I upload to a subdomain with a different database but when I try to access it, I get this error message:

```
<?php
/**
 * Front to the WordPress application. This file doesn't do anything, but loads
 * wp-blog-header.php which does and tells WordPress to load the theme.
 *
 * @package WordPress
 */

/**
 * Tells WordPress to load the WordPress theme and output it.
 *
 * @var bool
 */
define('WP_USE_THEMES', true);

/** Loads the WordPress Environment and Template */
require( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/wp-blog-header.php' );
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: The code you posted is not an error message...
Did you change all domain recurrences on the db to the new subdomain?

Comment: oh i'm forget upload php in my server. Thanks :)